# Star Wars Battlefront II Co-op?

Tags: pc, star-wars-battlefront-2

My room mate and I want to play through Star Wars Battlefront II's story campaign together on the PC. Is this possible via mods or download maps? The game supports Co-op on Xbox and PS2, but there is only fleeting mentions of co-op possibilities on Google for PC.

Comment: I believe the story campaign is single player only. Only the multiplayer supports co-op.

Comment: @Krazer I heard mentions of mods or modded servers that allowed story-line missions to be played co-op. I was hoping someone would know where to find them >.>

Comment: The campaign is not coop-able, but what you can do is have a race through campaign, which ive done a few times for this game and a few others. Dont forget to take into account accuracy. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use console commands to add maps to multiplayer but, I think they only work on dedicated servers. They play in reverse order. Here's what you will have type:

1. /addmap hot1g_c
2. /addmap yav1g_c
3. /addmap spa1g_c
4. /addmap tan1g_c
5. /addmap pol1g_c
6. /addmap dea1g_c (Bugs Online)
7. /addmap kam1c_c (Players Cannot Join)
8. /addmap mus1c_c (Auto Kick Bug)
9. /addmap spa4g_c (Bugs Online)
10. /addmap nab2g_c
11. /addmap cor1c_c
12. /addmap uta1c_c
13. /addmap kas2c_c
14. /addmap spa3c_c
15. /addmap fel1c_c
16. /addmap myg1c_c (Bugs Online)
17. /addmap geo1c_c

Comment: I haven't tried this solution but it seems resonable

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I could find anywhere there was no mod or add-ons that allowed you to do that. I'll keep on looking for it, and I'll get back to you if there is anything I find, but it's very unlikely- It's an old game and nothing new is likely to come up for a game released that long ago.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of the [Star Wars Battlefront Conversion Pack](http://www.moddb.com/mods/star-wars-battlefront-conversion-pack) mod is the ability to select "Campaign" as a mode in Instant Action, just like you would for Capture the Flag or Hero Assault modes, etc. Behind the scenes, it does the same thing as [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/118687/47878), just in a more user-friendly manner.

If both players have this mod enabled, you can run multiplayer games like this. Be aware that many of the scenarios have bugs when run in multiplayer and the game may crash.